# Get highest value from results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table

```
t1
--------------
id
date
val_1
val_2
```

I need to get 10 latest results and have them sorted from earlier to latest date, so I do it as

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM myTable
        WHERE project = $project_id
        ORDER BY date DESC
        LIMIT 10) AS results ORDER BY id ASC
```

Now, I need to get the highest value of val_1. I am trying to build a bar graph and would like to get the highest value because I need to divide it by the max height and use that result as a multiplier to stack-up val_1 and val_2 on top of each other without going outside of the graph's height.

Comment: Looks like you could use a single query: `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE project = $project_id ORDER BY date DESC, id ASC LIMIT 10` You can use `MAX` to get the maximum value of `val_1`

Comment: Wait, my query is overly complicated? Let me try your suggestion. How do I use MAX? Thanks.

Comment: [Example of getting the maximum value of a column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column.html)

Comment: I need the max value out of the set of results I retrieve. Shall I output it all into an array and then manipulate array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want something like this?

```
  SELECT *, 
         t2.biggest_value,
         ((t1.val_1/t2.biggest_value)*100) AS `%`
    FROM myTable t1
    JOIN (SELECT MAX(val_1) AS biggest_value,
                 project
            FROM myTable
         ) AS t2
      ON t2.project = t1.project
   WHERE t1.project = $project_id
ORDER BY date DESC, id ASC 
   LIMIT 10
```

The JOIN gets the highest value on `val_1` and the outer query is gathering all the data along with calculating the percentage of each `val_1` based on the max value.

[**Live DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bd91b/13/0)

Comment: Hmm, I think the demo site is down... I'm getting: Railo 3.3.4.003 Error (railo.runtime.net.mail.MailException) But let me give this query a whirl. Thanks.

Comment: @santa well the live demo is out of my hands you will have to wait for the owner to fix it however since you have it at hand let me know if it works for you.

Comment: OK, the site seems to be up. I have tweaked the dataset to make it more close to my actual data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ef87/3 There are still couple of issues that need to be addressed. The records needs to be rearranged by date from earlier to later. Currently it's in reverse, and the MAX value appears to be the largest of the entire set, not the one I retrieve. In the current example it should be 111. Thanks.

Comment: @santa that's because `date` needs to come first on the `ORDER BY` and not id like you had, you can also add `WHERE project = 234` to the join query see here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ef87/18

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
SELECT val_1 as max_val FROM myTable ORDER by val_1 DESC LIMIT 1
```

You can also try with `MAX` like

```
SELECT MAX(val_1) as max_val FROM myTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
SELECT *, MAX(val_1) FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM myTable
    WHERE project = $project_id
    ORDER BY date DESC
    LIMIT 10) AS results ORDER by id ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

See [3.6.1 The Maximum Value for a Column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column.html):

> “What is the highest item number?”

```
SELECT MAX(article) AS article FROM shop;
```

You are free to use `MAX()` on query results as well:

```
SELECT MAX(val_1) FROM (SELECT …) t;
```

Comment: I need the max value out of the set of results I retrieve.

Comment: Then replace `shop` with a subquery.

Comment: I actually changed my complex query to the one suggested by @Prix: SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE project = $project_id ORDER BY date DESC, id ASC LIMIT 10 I still need all these results in the order by date. In addition I need to find out the largest value of val_1, out of these results.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like;

```
SELECT MAX(val_1) FROM(SELECT *
        FROM myTable
        WHERE project = $project_id
        ORDER BY date DESC
        LIMIT 10) AS results ORDER by id ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

**This query will give you the max with other columns : -**

```
SELECT id,(select MAX(`price`) FROM `products` ) as FINAL from products
```

note :- *This query assemble id and max price from the product table .i.e It associate max price with each record set.*